# Whats up with JDK exceptions which do not allow exception chaining?

Tags: java, exception

There are a couple of exceptions I use regularly in the JDK which do not support exception chaining and have quite narrowed descriptions e.g.

- [`NoSuchElementException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html), "Thrown by the `nextElement` method of an `Enumeration` to indicate that there are no more elements in the enumeration" (updated to "Thrown by various accessor methods to indicate that the element being requested does not exist" in [JDK 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html))
- [`ParseException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html) "Signals that an error has been reached unexpectedly while parsing."

Should such exceptions not be used outside of the JDK? If so, what alternative exception would you recommend? If the exceptions can be used outside of JDK (without code smell),  how can I get exception chaining with those?

Comment: Do you mean wrapping other exceptions when you say exception chaining?

Comment: @Duncan That's what the Oracle tutorials say, so I'd presume so. Had to Google it, but it came up quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a chaining capability but it is not given via a constructor argument.

You can look at [Throwable.initCause(Throwable cause)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#initCause-java.lang.Throwable-) which may serve your purpose, but I believe these exceptions were coded specifically for the purpose they indicate.

For ParseException, this is specific to the operation in question, while the NoSuchElementException is very specific to something like array or other sorts of linear Collections.

Comment: "While most "new" exceptions seems to get chain-enabled constructors from the start, the "old" exceptions are getting chain-enabled constructors (for example, IOException in 1.6, AssertionError in 1.7) too, albeit very slowly. I hope that one day some Java maintains will just add missing constructors too each and every throwable class in JDK.